# Creating an image using typography

Tags: typography, terminology

I have an assignment where I need to create an image only using typography yet and I think it is similar to Ascii Art, am I correct?  Or what is this type of design called?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should ask whoever is giving you the assignment. Part of the assignment may be *how* you interpret it.

Comment: There's a wikipedia page for ASCII Art with example images. Have a look, see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard the term ASCII art in years - takes me back to the days of perforated paper rolls and daisy wheel printers. In that style, you're using letters as is to create a design/portrait affect. Incredibly creative way of using typography. But in the digital age, there's a genre called Typographic Portraiture. Here you're manipulating the letters and words - stretching, compressing, warping -  to create a visual effect. More of an illustration effect than unaltered typefaces.Interesting samples here from several artists:
https://www.domestika.org/en/blog/3558-5-typographic-portrait-artists-that-will-inspire-you
As mentioned, might be worth clarifying with your instructor - although you can take the creative initiative and interpret it on your own.

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing JeffK's answer. You can also transform a word into an image, or use typography as a texture, as shades, or as abstract forms. You can even make a sculpture made of letters.

Why you do not ask your professor, or better, use your imagination? That is the underlying idea.